# Install git on server without sudo

Tags: git, make, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install `git` on a server with a user that does not have root access.  I've seen a lot of tutorials that suggest using `./configure`, but when I downloaded the latest git zip from github, there was no such file.  Apparently it should just work with `make` and `make install`, but when I run `make`, I get errors:

```
In file included from credential-store.c:1:
cache.h:21: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'z_stream'
make: *** [credential-store.o] Error 1
```

Apparently this has to do with `zlib` not being installed.  I can download `zlib`, but I have no idea how to get `git` to know where I have installed it.  There may be other dependencies as well but I can probably handle them in a similar way.

I'd also like to just have the `git` executable alone in `/home/user/bin` without other folders or crap in there.  Is there any way I can just download the compiled executable?  Because that would be fine too.

Comment: What OS and/or distro?

Comment: @jjlin Debian squeeze

Comment: See also https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't currently have time to provide a super detailed answer, I can outline a possible strategy for running executables from a pre-built `git` package under your home directory. This response is aimed at Debian, since that's what you said you're using, but the basic concept is applicable to other OSes and distros as well.

First, go to http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/git and review the dependencies of the `git` package. Luckily, you'll find that `git` doesn't have that many. Most of the important ones are probably already installed, maybe with the exception of `libcurl3-gnutls` and `libexpat1`.

Next, download the binary .deb package and extract its contents (search the web to find out how to extract a .deb package manually). You'll find a `data.tar.gz` file. Extract that, and you'll get `usr/bin/git*` and `usr/lib/git-core/*` files. You can put these files somewhere under your home directory. Now the critical part: `/usr/bin/git` calls out to numerous "helper" programs under `/usr/lib/git-core`, and this latter path is hardcoded into `/usr/bin/git`. Luckily, you can override the hardcoded value by setting the `GIT_EXEC_PATH` environment variable, so update your dotfiles to point to where you decided to keep the various `/usr/lib/git-core` files.

Finally, it's possible that not all of the library dependencies (and their dependencies, etc, etc) were installed on your system (e.g., `libcurl3-gnutls`, `libexpat1`). You can download the binary packages for these as well, and extract them under your home directory, and then help `git` find them by setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable appropriately.

P.S. I've probably had more than my fair share of being in your position, so what I've outlined above is more than theoretical. But working around this sort of problem is a little bit of a black art, so there will usually be some additional fussing around involved. Good luck.

Comment: I downloaded the core from http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/git/git-core_1.7.10.4-1_all.deb and looked up how to extract the deb, but when I did all that is there is `usr/share/doc/git-core` which is a symlink to a nonexistent `git` file in the same directory.  Is there another place to download the .deb?

Comment: You need to download the `git` package, not `git-core`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **lot** of work ahead of you. You need to make sure their either wget or curl are available to you, since you will need one or the other of them to get the tarballs you need if the appropriate packages are not installed.

Create a

`/home/youruser/src` directory (`mkdir -p /home/youruser/src`).

cd into the src directory and get the source code to git

`wget  http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.11.2.tar.gz`

Untar it, and do

`./configure --help`

This will show you all the needed packages you will need, like expat, openssl, etc. You will have to dowload all of them, build and install them in `/home/youruser` When you are done you will have `/home/youruser/bin` along with several **needed** directories.

Please, read the INSTALL file in the untarred directory, and post your progress.

Comment: The git you linked to is a bit different (I got the `github` source which doesn't have `configure` at all).  I ran `./configure --with-zlib=/home/myname/zlib/` (that directory exists).  It didn't seem to complain.  However, when I run `make` I get the same error as above that seems to be a lack of `zlib`.  I'm stuck there.

Comment: Now, you need to download the source to zlib, unpack the tarball, do a `./configure --prefix=/home/youruser && make && make install` and retry git. As I said, if you do `./configure --help` with git you will get a list of packages it will want to have, they are marked `[default=yes]` or something like that.

Comment: Note: all this work is done for you with https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything