# How to install git on CentOS5 without root access?

Tags: git, centos

I'm trying to add git functionality to a production CentOS 5.5 system that has no development tools (since it is a production system).  So I don't have access to make/gcc/etc.  I basically want to install Git to be able to easily & quickly synchronize a website dir with my Git repo, so I have no need for compiling any source files.

I do not have root access, and for obvious reasons, root is does not want to install Git on a prod system, but is okay if I can set it up locally for my own use.

I've tried to download and unpack a git-core.rpm into my home dir and although I am able run some functionality of git, none of git's dependencies are where it expects them and so it fails.

My structure looks like the following:

```
~/git
~/git/usr
~/git/usr/bin
~/git/usr/share
~/git/usr/share/doc
~/git/usr/share/git-core
~/git/usr/share/locale
~/git/usr/share/man
```

When I run something like `git help clone`, I get an error msg `No manual entry for git-clone`.  This is confirmed by `git --man-path` (/usr/share/man).  Other commands fail similarly.

How can I tell git to use `~/git` as the root instead of `/` as the root to all git dependencies without recompiling?  I cannot seem to find any environment vars or git vars that I can set.

There is a similar question posted on [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2647484/827480), but unfortunately both solutions offered are not viable - ie: recompile git (I don't have any make tools) or unpack the rpm (have tried but as indicated, git looks for predefined paths).

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/450791/130030), I have tried setting GIT_EXEC_PATH but with minimal success as well:

```
[eric ~]$ export GIT_EXEC_PATH=~/git/usr/bin/git
[eric ~]$ git --man-path
/usr/share/man
[eric ~]$ git help clone
No manual entry for git-clone
[eric ~]$ git --exec-path
/home/eric/git/usr/bin/git
```

Comment: How did you install git-core.rpm in your home dir?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647484/installing-git-in-home-directory-centos-5-no-root

Comment: @Satish - I downloaded git-1.7.10.2-1.w5.i386.rpm and used `rpm2cpio  git-1.7.10.2-1.w5.i386.rpm | cpio -idmv`

Comment: @jjlin - It is similar to that question, yes, but not a duplicate.  Perhaps I should have linked to that question in my original post - I'll edit it to make the correction.  Unfortunately, the solutions offered in that SO post are not applicable (ie: download source and recompile as I do not have make tools, or just extract the rpm as extracting the rpm does not work).

Comment: @jjlin - it is mentioned in the other post, but from a quick google to understand what it does, it seemed to be related to the msysGit project and/or the build process.  I updated my question with the info relating to GIT_EXEC_PATH as well.

Comment: Also, I do have `git` running on a CentOS 5.8 system, but it is built from source. If you have access to another CentOS 5 system with development tools installed, I could provide specific instructions on building from source, if the build process is what you're worried about.

Comment: @jjlin I am trying to avoid setting up a duplicate CentOs 5.5 environment with build tools just to build git binaries.  I am very surprised to find out that this cannot be done without rebuilding the binaries!  I was sure there would be a way to configure git to work without having to rebuild everything.

Comment: It can be done, as I mentioned, by setting `GIT_EXEC_PATH`. See, e.g., http://git-scm.com/docs/git for a description of this env var. You will want to set it to point to the path of the `git-core` directory that gets extracted. There may be other things you'll need to do, however, which I discuss in my Superuser post. Surprising or not, the reality is that most larger Unix programs have hardcoded paths that complicate a simple relocation, so it's not just a Git thing.

Comment: if you want to keep a repo on a remote machine w/o git you can use push via ftp or ssh to that machine without having git installed there. Doesn't answer your question but might solve your problem.

Comment: @three I realize that, but just adds an extra step for me to create a local working copy that is based on a tag to push to the machine.  If I can get git working on the server, then I can just pull changes and reset to the right tag.  Am trying to be a little lazy. :)

Comment: absolutely, just adding an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the RPM is set  up for relocation (the vast majority isn't) you can't do it that way. Best bet is getting stuff installed officially, so it will be tracked/updated with the rest of the system.

If that can't be done, you could do something like:

1. Fetch latest source
2. Configure with e.g. "configure prefix=$HOME ..."
3. Build and install, e.g. "make install"
4. Figure out what comes from git, at least stuff in ~/bin/, ~/share/man/, ~/libexec/,
   pack that up and transfer it to the victim machine
5. Unpack on the victim and try it out. Put ~/bin at the *end* of yout PATH

But please don't do it without first making sure with the Powers That Be that this is OK by them.